# Override ExpiresDefault set in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to override an expires default directive set in an htaccess file.

I have taken over a site which had an expires default set to 1 year.

After making some changes, they are not taking effect, even after clearing the cache - i believe it is down to this setting?

Comment: Can you copy the .htaccess for testing?